# Steam keys on gamersgate

Tags: steam, just-cause-2

I am thinking of buying a game on [Gamersgate](http://www.gamersgate.com/) but I was wondering if you get a steam key when you buy it. For instance I want to buy [Just Cause 2](http://www.gamersgate.com/DD-JC2/just-cause-2), but I have heard some games are redeemed via steam and others not on Gamersgate. How do I find this out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Games which work only with Steam and where you get a Steam key to redeem are noted as such in the [DRM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_rights_management) section of the game's information box.

[image]